# How to split a string in r by a delimiter and discard the last two items?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a string separated by `_` and I want to get rid of the last two elements. For example, from `A_B_C_D` I want to return `A_B`, and from `A_B_C_D_E` I want `A_B_C`. I have tried `str_split_fixed` from `stringr`:

```
my_string <- "A_B_C_D"
x <- str_split_fixed(my_string,"_",3)
```

but it returns `"A"  "B"  "C_D"` instead of  `"A_B" "C" "D"`, otherwise I could have done `head(x,-2)` to get `A_B`

Is there a better way than

```
paste(head(unlist(strsplit(my_string,"_")),-2),collapse="_")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a regex:

```
sub('(_[A-Z]){2}$', '', 'A_B_C_D')
```

Where the number `2` is the length you want to drop.

Comment: (+1) As I suspected, that's a much better regex than what I came up with.

Comment: I almost deleted my answer and commented on yours :)

Comment: It's funny how many of us reached for regex to answer this question.  Anyone who does data parsing needs to learn regular expressions as an established toolbox favorite.

Comment: Awesome, although I would make it more general `sub('(_[^_]+){2}$','','AA_BB_C-C_DD') # AA_BB`

Comment: Excellent extension of my answer.  As a rule, I like to make my regular expressions specific as possible to start with.  Then as I find edge cases I expand them.  If they are too broad at the start, you'll loose edge cases in the other direction that you potentially wanted to keep.